# How to use LoginRequiredMixin with UserPassesTestMixin correctly

Tags: django, django-views

I have a custom view with `LoginRequiredMixin` and `UserPassesTestMixin`:

```
class CustomListView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, ListView):
    template_name = '_global/_list.html'

    raise_exception = True
    permission_denied_message = 'You must select an issuer.'

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.session.get('issuer_pk', None) is not None
```

This works as expected unless I access the view with an anonymous user, in which case I get the 403 error and not a login redirect.

The desired behaviour is to first require an authenticated user and then pass the tests. Have I got the inheritance wrong somehow?

Answer (score 3):

The order of inheritance is correct. It will first check whether the user is logged in. Is the user not logged in? Then it calls `handle_no_permission` and doesn't check for the `test_func`. If the user is logged in, it continues and checks the `test_func` and calls `handle_no_permission` when the user does not pass the test.

`LoginRequiredMixin` and `UserPassesTestMixin` both call the `handle_no_permission` method that they inherit from `AccessMixin`. That method looks like this:

```py
class AccessMixin:
    def handle_no_permission(self):
        if self.raise_exception:
            raise PermissionDenied(self.get_permission_denied_message())
        return redirect_to_login(self.request.get_full_path(), self.get_login_url(), self.get_redirect_field_name())
```

Since you've set `raise_exception` to `True`, in case of a user not being logged it also raises an exception. What I understand from your question is that you want to redirect the user to the login page in case the user is not logged in, but you do want to raise an exception as soon as the user does not pass the test. One solution would be to do something like this (note that it doesn't call `handle_no_permission`, but directly redirects to the login):

```py
class CustomLoginRequiredMixin(AccessMixin):
    """Verify that the current user is authenticated."""
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect_to_login(request.get_full_path(), self.get_login_url(), self.get_redirect_field_name())
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And then inherit from this class instead of the vanilla `LoginRequiredMixin`:

```py
class CustomListView(CustomLoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, ListView):
    template_name = '_global/_list.html'

    raise_exception = True
    permission_denied_message = 'You must select an issuer.'

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.session.get('issuer_pk', None) is not None
```

Comment: Thanks. So are you saying the same as Arakkal, that I have to overwrite the `dispatch` for the `LoginRequiredMixin`? This seems a little counter-intuitive. It means every time I change my UserPassesTestMixin I have to also rewrite the LoginRequiredMixin? Is there another way?

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that you do want to raise an exception for the `UserPassesTestMixin`, but you don't want to raise an exception for the `LoginRequiredMixin` (you just want a redirect to the login page). Since both classes are looking at the same class attribute `raise_exception`, you do have to overwrite one of them to change its behaviour. Note that Arakkal's example doesn't work since it will still show a 403 if you set `raise_exception` to `True` on your `CustomListView`. Also note that you only have to rewrite `LoginRequiredMixin` once and use that for all your classes.

Comment: Thanks. When I set `exception=False` it behaves as expected. However, I now get an error `name 'request' is not defined` when processing the test? Do I need to `super()` something?

Comment: I've edited the `CustomLoginRequiredMixin` so that it uses the `request` from the arguments passed to the `dispatch` method instead of `self.request`. Can you test if that works now? And if now, can you tell on which line it gives an error?

Answer (score 1):

The [LoginRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin) and [UserPassesTestMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) classes are being called inside the **`dispatch(...)`** method of ***view***.

In your case, Django/Python executes the **`dispatch`** method of **LoginRequiredMixin** (we know, that's how inheritance works!!). In order to execute all permissions checks, you need to override the **`dispatch`** method that calls every authentication method separately.

```
class MyPermissionMixin(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_test_result = self.get_test_func()()
        if not request.user.is_authenticated or not user_test_result:
            return self.handle_no_permission()
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


class CustomListView(MyPermissionMixin, ListView):
    ...
    # other code snippet
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems a little counter-intuitive. It means every time I change my `UserPassesTestMixin` I have to also rewrite the `LoginRequiredMixin`? Is there anotherway?

Comment: Why do you need to change the `UserPassesTestMixin`? Can you elaborate a little?

Answer (score 0):

If it's acceptable to replace LoginRequiredMixin by login_required in method_decorator, it can redirect an unauthenticated user to login first, with redirect to the page for test after login.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@method_decorator([login_required], name='dispatch')
class CustomListView(UserPassesTestMixin, ListView):  # remove LoginRequiredMixin
```